# Rounded corners of my uiview are updated during the pushSegue

Tags: ios, navigation, push, transition, cornerradius

My controllers view have bottom corners. When I push from `VC1` to `VC2`, during the transition it will get sharp corner and after transition it sets the round corner. I wanted my views to be rounded during the transition. For more accuracy check the below GIF.

**Video example (corner bottom reseted during transition)**

[image]

**Code VC 1** (vc push button)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

**Code VC 2** (second vc)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Comment: specify your issue clearly .

Comment: @dahiya_boy At the moment of the transition, the rounded edges of the blue uiview are reset to 0, I would like them to remain round, you understand?

Comment: when you push from one VC to another there is an intermediate called **transition**. you have to code in this state to get desired output. You got lots of tutorials regarding this but each tutorial defines some new animation but you make sure you do your own. It any other help or issue you can ask.